# Kendo UI MVVM Datasource binding to html input element

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

newbie to kendo

The kendo datasource only returns arrays and my RESTful api returns a client as an array of one element.

However, I cannot seem to bind the 'Name' field of the client to an html input box.

I can however consume the data if I put it in a 'ul', as shown in the below code.  I know the json response is well formed because I can  console.log(obj[0].Name);

I attempted to return obj[0] in the data: of the datasource but that just broke everything. (no slice error message, as it tries to slice up the array).

I'm sure this is easy but I must be just thinking about this all wrong...

Html and js below:

```
<div data-role="view" data-title="Client Detail" data-model="app.clientView">

<!-- this does not work -->

<input data-bind="value: app.clientView.data"/>
<input data-bind="value: app.clientView.data[0].Name"/>
<input data-bind="value: app.clientView.data.Name"/>

<!-- this works -->

<ul data-role="listview" data-source="app.clientView.data" data-template="client-template"></ul> 

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="client-template">
    <a href="components/clientView/view.html?id=#: ID #">
        <div>#: Name #</div>
        <div>#: LastActivityOn #</div>
    </a>
</script>
```

```js
app.clientView = kendo.observable({
    data: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: app.uri + "clients/69", //+ id,
                type: "get",
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function (req) {
                    req.setRequestHeader('X-authKey', app.key);
                }
            }
  },
        schema: {
         data: function (response) {
             console.log(response);
             var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
                console.log(obj[0].Name);
             return obj;
         }
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kendo UI MVVM [**value**](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/value) bindings cannot point to a Kendo UI DataSource instance. Only [**source**](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/source) bindings can do that.

In your case, rework your implementation and add some new fields to the viewModel (`app.clientView`), which can be used for value bindings. It is OK to [populate](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/observableobject#set-field-values) these fields [after the DataSource instance receives its data](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-change).

On a side note, there is no need to specify viewModel fields verbosely by including the viewModel reference in the bindings configuration. You only need the field names there. Check the [Kendo UI MVVM demos](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mvvm/index).

Comment: Very helpful but I can't quite get it to work. If I remove my listview in the above example it seems the view model data: and schema: data; are never run. I added a Name: field and set it in schema: data with the listview present and it works, without the listview it does not.  I added a change: to get the success of the restfull call, but it never fires.  Manually calling clientView.data.read(); locks up the emulator.  Despite all that I feel I'm getting close. :P  I'm going over your answer carefully, losts of good stuff there.

Comment: The Kendo UI DataSource does not make requests, unless it is told to do so by a databound widget or by the developer. The locking up that you are talking about is probably a separate problem - check for JavaScript errors.

Comment: I had to do a workaround on this because my rest url is in the form .../clients/{id}, where {id} depends on the previous view.  Best I could figure the url in the url: portion of the transport is resolved when the scrip is loaded, long before I set the global variable id.  The workaround was to call a loadClient function in the view onShow handler and then doing a typical ajax call - then with jQuery I set my html elements - solving both my issues in an easy and familiar way. I marked this as the answer because it is the answer to the question I asked.